# Multiple Views - One ViewModel MVVM Light in SL4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

Greetings -

I am writing an app that ultimately will need two UI implementations. The first will be the standard app that the majority of our clients will use. The second is a custom implementation that our biggest client is asking us to design for them. This is more than just swapping out a style or skin... in some instances, we use an Accordion (RadPanelBar, truly) for one version, but will be using a TabControl in the other.

Because I'm using EventToCommand, the ViewModel code is identical. I just modeled this using a tab control & a RadPanelBar, and the effect was the same... simply wire my EventToCommand to the proper controls, and everything worked as expected.

I understand that the View to ViewModel relationship is typically 1:1. In my scenario, I want it to be 2:1, where every viewModel has 2 associated views. With about 50 views required per app, that's 100 Views total to 50 ViewModels.

First question - can this be done? 
Second question - am I on the right track?
Third question - Given a "yes" to first question, How does implemention work? Do i need to duplicate code in my Locator to wire up ViewModel1 with View1A and View1B?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your approach is correct.

I think that is really stupid if we need to have 2 VM for 2 Views that does the same thing.

The 1:1 scenario is when you have views-vm that does different things not for two representations of the same thing.

How to do that? You don't have to duplicate code in the locator. Just wire the two views to the same ViewModel (already on the Locator) in the DataContext property.

Comment: Exactly. I do that all the time.